# how to add group and sum of group programmatically in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-grid

In my case I have to group in a Kendo grid and execute the sum of the groups programmatically.

In my case, I can store the code directly in the grid with :

```
group: [{ field: "age", aggregates: [ { field: "age", aggregate: "sum" }] }]
```

how is this stored as code programmatily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution looks like this:

[Sample in dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/uHiyenUb/4)

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
           var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                                                                           data: [
        { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
        { name: "Jane Doo", age: 30 },
        { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
    ]      
});  
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,     
           groupable: true,
    columns: [
      { 
        field: "name"
      },
      { 
        field: "age",
 //     groupFooterTemplate: "Total: #= sum #"
      }
    ],
}).data("kendoGrid");
           grid.dataSource.group([
           { field: "age", aggregates: [ 
                                 { field: "age", aggregate: "sum" }
                                ] 
    }
           ]);

           $.each(grid.columns, function(key, vs){
console.log(grid.columns[key].field);
  if(grid.columns[key].field == "age"){
           grid.columns[key].groupFooterTemplate = "Total: #= sum #";
  }   
});
           grid.refresh();
</script>
```

If there are better solutions, I am very happy to take them over.